# Ruby and bash unzip - error renaming files

Tags: ruby, bash, rename, unzip, file-rename

Problem. I have x amount of zip files, each with n amount of audio files. Each audio file has the same name, so when I do a dump unzip I have to rename the files in terminal. my plan is to cycle though the zip files and for every audio file extract it and rename it. The error is coming when I try to rename the file I have extracted - even though I can see it in the folder.

Where am I going wrong?

```
script_dir = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
Dir.chdir(script_dir)


Dir.glob('*.pencast').each do |pencast|

    i = 1

    `unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}'`.each do |zipped_audio|

    pencast_title = File.basename(File.basename(pencast), '.*')
    audio_title = File.basename(zipped_audio)
    audio_extension = File.extname(File.basename(zipped_audio))
    renamed = "#{pencast_title}-#{i}#{audio_extension}"

    `unzip -j #{pencast} #{audio_title}`
    File.rename(audio_title, renamed)

    i += 1          
    end
end
```

Output is:

```
prog2.rb:20:in `rename': No such file or directory - audio-0.aac (Errno::ENOENT)
 or Cancer1-1-1.aac
    from prog2.rb:20
    from prog2.rb:11:in `each'
    from prog2.rb:11
    from prog2.rb:7:in `each'
    from prog2.rb:7
```

I can find the files, I can unzip the files I want, but It doesn't seem to like me trying to rename them.

I think my problem is perhaps that `unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}'` is finding 2 files. I'll add `| awk 'NR==1'` and see if I can get somewhere

Comment: Can you post the output of `unzip -l #{pencast}` and also a directory listing after that command

Comment: I think I know what the problem is... How do I use `File.rename("text1.txt", "text2.txt")` with variables? ie `var1 = "text1.txt"` and `var2 = "text2.txt"`

Comment: `File.rename(var1, var2)` should do it. If that's even a question you need to get yourself a decent Ruby reference manual.

Comment: @tadman, for some reason it doesn't - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042026/renaming-files-using-variables-in-ruby/9042224#9042224

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing *anything* with bash; why wouldn't you just use Ruby to find the `.aac` files??? This is nuts.

Comment: because apparently ruby does not have in build un zip capabilities, so I'm using bash `unzip`. I have been using ruby for 1 day, so please forgive my errors... If you have a suggestion I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are the zipped_audio files contained in subdirectories within the ZIP archives? If not, why do you use `File.basename(zipped_audio)`?