# renaming files using variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, renaming

How do you use variables to rename files in Ruby?

```
File.rename("text1.txt", "text2.txt")
```

The above example is fine when using irb, but I writing a script where both var1 and var2 are unknown to me.

for example:

```
script_dir = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
Dir.chdir(script_dir)

Dir.glob('Cancer1-1.pencast').each do |pencast| 
pencast_title = File.basename(File.basename(pencast), '.*')
i = 1
audio_title = File.basename(`unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}' | awk 'NR=='#{i}''`)   
audio_path = `unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}' | awk 'NR=='#{i}''`
audio_extension = File.extname(File.basename(audio_path))
new_name = "#{pencast_title}-#{i}#{audio_extension}"
File.rename(audio_title, new_name)
```

does not work...
but if i use `puts var1` I see the file name I want.

The error I get is:

```
prog_test.rb:12:in `rename': No such file or directory - audio-0.aac (Errno::ENOENT)
 or Cancer1-1-1.aac
    from prog_test.rb:12
    from prog_test.rb:5:in `each'
    from prog_test.rb:5
```

but the file `audio-0.aac` is there... I'm looking at it.

---

I am certain I have located the problem:
it seems to be adding a variable to another variable. This is a simplified example that produces the same output:

```
audio_title = "audio-0.aac"
fullPath = File::SEPARATOR + "Users" + File::SEPARATOR + "name" + File::SEPARATOR + "Desktop" + File::SEPARATOR + audio_title
newname = File::SEPARATOR + "Users" + File::SEPARATOR + "name" + File::SEPARATOR + "Desktop" + File::SEPARATOR + "audio1.aac"

puts fullPath
puts newname

File.rename(fullPath, newname)
```

OUTPUT :

```
/Users/name/Desktop/audio-0.aac
/Users/name/Desktop/audio1.aac
prog_test.rb:22:in `rename': No such file or directory - /Users/name/Desktop/audio-0.aac or /Users/name/Desktop/audio1.aac (Errno::ENOENT)
    from prog_test.rb:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the full file path to `File.rename`, not just the basename

I am not sure what is going on in your example inside `File.basename()` , but imagine the following:

```
  fullPath = "C:" + File::SEPARATOR + "Folder" + File::SEPARATOR + "File.txt" # C:\Folder\File.txt
  basename = File.basename(fullPath) # File
  newFileName = "File.bak"

  File.rename(basename, newFileName)
  # How can Ruby possibly know which directory to find the above file in, or where to put it? - It will just look in the current working directory
```

So instead, you need to pass the full path to File.rename, like so:

```
  fullPath = "C:" + File::SEPARATOR + "Folder" + File::SEPARATOR + "File.txt" # C:\Folder\File.txt
  directory = File.dirname(fullPath) # C:\Folder
  newFileName = "File.bak"

  File.rename(fullPath, directory + File::SEPARATOR + newFileName)
```

Comment: I specify in the beginning of the script the working directory. So ruby knows where it is. I have tried giving the full path name however, but still the same. I'll try again...

Comment: Can you put comments next to each of your variables to show their value (i.e. what you get from using `puts` or `p` on them)? It would make debugging a lot easier? Also, I notice you've made multiple edits to your question; are you showing all of your code now?

Comment: The problem seems to be: `audio_title = File.basename(`unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}' | awk 'NR=='#{i}''`)` do I need to convert is somehow to a different type of sting?

Comment: I'm trying to make it clearer. I didn't want to put everything as it complicates things a bit. I am trying to cut out the parts that are needed and going wrong, so I can test them separately to the rest of the script.

Comment: What is the value of `audio_title`? A String is a String, so provided it has the correct value (the correct filename), that shouldn't be a problem. I have to admit that I don't understand what you are doing with `unzip -l #{pencast} | grep .aac | awk '{print $4;}' | awk 'NR=='#{i}''`, but the double `'` near the end of the line looks unusual. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: The line is using bash's unzip... -l lets me look into the file which is called by variable #{pencast}. I then grep for aac files... use awk to print column 4 of the output which contains the path name, and then use awk NR to select a line number (as there are often more than one aac file in the zip. the double quote at the end is used because `awk 'NR=='#{i}''` is calling a variable. usually it would be `awk 'NR==1'` or `awk 'NR==2'`. If there is a cleaner way of doing this, then I would love to - but as I don't I make the most of bash...